# Как запретить windows закрывать приложение при выходе из системы

Tags: python

я создаю свой текстовый редактор, мне нужно, чтобы если пользователь не сохранит данные, он не мог выйти из системы

Comment: Вы там изобретаете vim, что ли?

Comment: По моему лучше ,если редактор закрывается, создавать бэкап того, что в данный момент написано.

Comment: я имею в виду, если это он делает сам своими руками

Comment: При попытке выхода из программы, проверяйте, есть ли изменённый текст. Если есть - отменяйте выход. / Заведите булеву переменную. Когда пользователь хоть что-то меняет в тексте (добавляет, изменяет, удаляет), меняйте значение этой переменной. Её и проверяйте при выходе.